# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<List<dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, sqlite, listview

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora que quiero crear una lista para ver mis prospectos que estoy guardando en mi database sqflite, me arroja el siguiente error:

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future<List>'

El problema es que no encuentro donde esta mi error, tengo la función en la database, mi provider y el home_page que es donde lo mando llamar:

función en la base de datos:

```
Future<List<ProspectModel>> getAllProspects() async {
    final db = await database;
    final resp = await db.query('Prospect');

    List<ProspectModel> list = resp.isNotEmpty
        ? resp.map((p) => ProspectModel.fromJson(p)).toList()
        : [];

    return list;
  }
```

tambien intente:

```
Future<List<ProspectModel>> getAllProspects() async {
    final db = await database;
    final resp = await db.query('Prospect');

    return resp.isNotEmpty
        ? resp.map((p) => ProspectModel.fromJson(p)).toList()
        : [];
  }
```

prospect_provider.dart:

```
class ProspectProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  List<ProspectModel> prospects = [];

  String selectType = 'http';



  Future<ProspectModel> newProspect(String valor) async {

    final newProspect = new ProspectModel();
    final id = await DBProvider.db.newProspect(newProspect);

    //asigna el ID de la db al modelo
    newProspect.id = id;
    this.prospects.add(newProspect);

    notifyListeners();
  }


  viewProspects() async {

    final prospects = await DBProvider.db.getAllProspects();

    this.prospects = [...prospects];
    notifyListeners();
  }


  deleteProspect(int id) async {

    await DBProvider.db.deletePros(id);
    this.viewProspects();
  }
}
```

home_page.dart:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  final prospectProvider = new ProspectProvider();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final bloc = Provider.of(context);
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Home')),

      body: FutureBuilder<List>(
        future: prospectProvider.viewProspects(),
        initialData: List(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final prospects = snapshot.data;

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: prospects.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) => _createItem(context, prospects[i]),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _createButton(context),
    );
  }

  _createItem(BuildContext context, ProspectModel prospect) {

    return new ListTile(
      title: Text(prospect.nombreNucleo),
      subtitle: Text(prospect.nombreContacto),
    );
  }

  _createButton(BuildContext context) {

    return FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/prospecto');
        });
  }
}
```

porspect_model.dart

```
ProspectModel prospectModelFromJson(String str) =>

ProspectModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));


String prospectModelToJson(ProspectModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());


class ProspectModel {

  ProspectModel({

    this.id,
    //this.idTp,
    this.nombreNucleo = '',
    this.nombreContacto = '',
    this.municipioProspecto = '',
    this.telefonoProspecto,
    this.emailProspecto = '',
    this.observacionesProspecto = '',
    //id usuario viene del servidor
    //this.usuAlta,
    this.fechaAlta = '',
    //this.idCliente,
    this.statusPros = true,
    this.hectareasAprox = 0.0,
  });


  int id;

  //int idTp;

  String nombreNucleo;

  String nombreContacto;

  String municipioProspecto;

  String telefonoProspecto;

  String emailProspecto;

  String observacionesProspecto;

  //int usuAlta;

  String fechaAlta;

  //int idCliente;

  bool statusPros;

  double hectareasAprox;



  factory ProspectModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProspectModel(

        id: json["id"],
        //idTp: json["id_tp"],
        nombreNucleo: json["nombre_nucleo"],
        nombreContacto: json["nombre_contacto"],
        municipioProspecto: json["municipio_prospecto"],
        telefonoProspecto: json["telefono_prospecto"],
        emailProspecto: json["email_prospecto"],
        observacionesProspecto: json["observaciones_prospecto"],
        //usuAlta: json["usu_alta"],
        fechaAlta: json["fecha_alta"],
        //idCliente: json["idCliente"],
        statusPros: json["status_pros"],
        hectareasAprox: json["hectareas_Aprox"],
      );


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {

        "id": id,
        //"id_tp": idTp,
        "nombre_nucleo": nombreNucleo,
        "nombre_contacto": nombreContacto,
        "municipio_prospecto": municipioProspecto,
        "telefono_prospecto": telefonoProspecto,
        "email_prospecto": emailProspecto,
        "observaciones_prospecto": observacionesProspecto,
        //"usu_alta": usuAlta,
        "fecha_alta": fechaAlta,
        //"idCliente": idCliente,
        "status_pros": statusPros,
        "hectareas_Aprox": hectareasAprox,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define el tipo de dato de respuesta en tus métodos:

Cambia

```dart
viewProspects() async {
```

Por

```dart
Future<List<ProspectModel>> viewProspects() async {

return this.prospects;
```

De igual manera con el `FutureBuilder`, cambia

```dart
 FutureBuilder<List>(
    future: prospectProvider.viewProspects(),
    initialData: List(),
```

Por

```dart
 FutureBuilder<List<ProspectModel>>(
    future: prospectProvider.viewProspects(),
    initialData: List<ProspectModel>(),
```

Comment: Hola mil gracias por tu respuesta, pude resolver la parte del error, solo que ahora me muestra el circular progress indicator y sigue sin mostrarme mis datos, tengo algún otro error, me comenta que en la parte del provider donde agregue Future<List<ProspectModel>> viewProspects() async {, necesita un retorno, de verdad es que soy nueva en esto y no entiendo muy bien aún.

Comment: agrega más detalle en tu pregunta , con los errores que aparecen

Comment: Es que ya no es un error solo no muestra el listado se queda cargando, y en la parte del provider Future<List<ProspectModel>> viewProspects() async {
    final prospects = await DBProvider.db.getAllProspects();

    this.prospects = [...prospects];
    notifyListeners();
  }, me marca una advertencia la cual es la siguient:  This function has a return type of 'FutureOr<List<ProspectModel>>', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

Comment: ya actualicé mi respuesta, necesitas retornar el future,  Future<List<ProspectModel>> viewProspects() async {

return this.prospects;       no estas retornando nada en ese metodo, solo refrescando la vista pero el futurebuilder sigue esperando respuesta.  Te recomiendo mi canal de youtube, tengo unos videos sobre gestión de estado y blo : youtube.com/diegoveloper

Comment: Listo ya se quito el circular progress indicator sigo sin ver mis datos, veré tu canal para entender mejor mi error, mil gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: en este momento no regresa nada de datos creo es porque no esta accediendo a la db de sqflite.